# Build path libraries cannot be manipulated in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a Java application that was developed using Eclipse Luna. There are multiple projects in the workspace and each has several dependencies on 3rd party libraries. The problem is I can't figure out how to change these. If I select a library under Project Explorer the Delete option is greyed out. If I open the the Java Build Path window Libraries tab and select one there, all the buttons on the right are greyed out. What's causing this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like they were set using Gradle, in which case you should update the gradle build first, then have it regenerate the Eclipse project metadata like the Java Build Path.

Comment: @nitind Post this as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they were set using Gradle, in which case you should update the gradle build first, then have it regenerate the Eclipse project metadata like the Java Build Path (using the `cleanEclipse` and `eclipse` tasks).